# on blur validate input text fields based on class

Tags: jquery

I have a form containing 5 - 6 phone fields in the form of text fields. Only one is visible in the beginning. Other fields are displayed based on certain conditions. All these phone fields have a common class "phoneclass". I am validating these fields on click of the submit button. That is working fine.
Now I need to validate these fields on blur of the field as well. I am not able to do it using my code. Can somebody please help me in this?

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/NjvJU/8/

HTML

```
 <div class="phoneclass">
<label for="owner_phone">Owner Phone:</label>
<div class="input-phone">
    <input type="text" id="owner_area_code" name="owner_area_code" minlength="3" maxlength="3" title="Owner number has either been left blank or the data entered was invalid" style="width: 60px" /> <span class="inline-text">-</span>

    <input type="text" id="owner_local3" name="owner_local3" minlength="3" maxlength="3" title="Owner number has either been left blank or the data entered was invalid" style="width: 60px" /> <span class="inline-text">-</span>

    <input type="text" id="owner_local4" name="owner_local4" minlength="4" maxlength="4" title="Owner number has either been left blank or the data entered was invalid" style="width: 60px" /> <span class="inline-text">Ext.</span>

    <input type="text" id="owner_extn" name="owner_extn" maxlength="5" style="width: 40px" />
    <input type="hidden" id="owner_phone" />
</div>
</div>
<hr/>
<div class="phoneclass">
<label for="owner_phone1">Owner Phone1:</label>
<div class="input-phone">
    <input type="text" id="owner_area_code1" name="owner_area_code1" minlength="3" maxlength="3" title="Owner number has either been left blank or the data entered was invalid" style="width: 60px" /> <span class="inline-text">-</span>

    <input type="text" id="owner_local31" name="owner_local31" minlength="3" maxlength="3" title="Owner number has either been left blank or the data entered was invalid" style="width: 60px" /> <span class="inline-text">-</span>

    <input type="text" id="owner_local41" name="owner_local41" minlength="4" maxlength="4" title="Owner number has either been left blank or the data entered was invalid" style="width: 60px" /> <span class="inline-text">Ext.</span>

    <input type="text" id="owner_extn1" name="owner_extn1" maxlength="5" style="width: 40px" />
    <input type="hidden" id="owner_phone1" />
 </div>
 </div>
<div>
<input type="submit" id="submitBtn" />
</div>
```

JS

```
$('#submitBtn').click(function () {
$('.phoneclass').filter(':visible').each(function () {
    var arr=new Array();
    input.find('input[type=text]').each(function (index, value) {
        //alert($(value).val());
        arr.push($(value).val());
    });
    var first = arr[0];
    var sec = arr[1];
    validateFn(first,sec); 
});
});

$('.phoneclass').each(function () {
    $(this).find('input').each(function (index, value) {
        $(this).blur(function(){
            alert("blur");
            arr.push($(value).val());
            var first = arr[0];
            var sec = arr[1]; 
            alert(first+" "+sec);
            //validateFn(first,sec);
        });
    });
});

function validateFn(val1,val2){
//Validation code
var test1=val1;
var test2=val2;
alert(test1+test2);
return true;
}
```

I should not be using id's for validation. Thats y I am using the div class for iterating through each field and doing the validation. Any idea how I can validate on blur of the fields?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding define below line at top

```
 var arr=new Array();
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NjvJU/7/)

Try my [updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NjvJU/10/)

Comment: Sorry..that was a typo..have updated my fiddle..Thanks for pointing this..even after initializing array outside, blur event doesnt happen correctly...

Comment: @Amit..I tried the updated fiddle. bUt its not alerting the value of the field on blur..